# Add unique value to each iterate element HTML Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a problem with Angular 2.
I want to made List HTML like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>
   <li>..
</ul>
```

With links but I don't know how to add iterate argument to HTML object in NG2.
It is my code:

```
<ul>
    <li   *ngFor="let item of geoNames | filterBy: userFilter" 
                   (click)="showNameG= !showNameG" >
        <a>{{ item.name }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div *ngIf="showNazwyG">
     <show-NameG></show-NameG>
</div>
```

And I want to add a different name to each of the element li to recognize from has been clicked. In AngularJS worked something like this:

```
(click)="showNameG{{index}}= !showNameG{{index}}"
```

Comment: [ngFor](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html) does have a nice an explanatory manual page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*ngFor` provides an `index` context variable

```
<li *ngFor="let item of geoNames | filterBy: userFilter; let i=index"
    (click)="showNameG[i]= !showNameG[i]" ><a>{{ item.name }}</a></li>
```

**update**

```
<li *ngFor="let item of geoNames | filterBy: userFilter; let i=index"
    (click)="self['showNameG'] + i = !self['showNameG']" ><a>{{ item.name }}</a></li>
```

```
export class MyComponent {
  get self() { 
    return this;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Yes it is working but how to relate to this in *ngIf
<div *ngIf="showNazwyG[0]"> </div>
DictionaryComponent.html:10 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined this error when i click on it

Comment: I misinterpreted your question a bit. You would need something like `(click)="self.['showName' + i] = ! self.['showName' + i]` with `get self() { return this;}` in the components class. Perhaps even `(click)="this.['showName' + i] = ! this.['showName' + i]` works (without an additional getter), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Just an additional hint: `{{}}` **never** works together with `[foo]` or `(foo)`. Either one or the other, but never both.

Answer (score 1):

Use `item`, create a property `showNameG` and toggle its value

```
<li *ngFor="let item of geoNames | filterBy: userFilter" (click)="item.showNameG=!item.showNameG" ></li>
```

Comment: In an Ideal world I agree this is best practice ( and what I do ). But since the OP mentions `index` in AnguarJS context, it might be handy to show them the equivalent thing.

Comment: @NeilLunn, As Günter Zöchbauer already covered that adding now will demean his answer. So sticking with it for now

Comment: this solution can't working becouse the name of item can be 2 or more words.

Answer (score 0):

You must add following to your *ngFor:

```
let index = index;
```

At the end you should have this:

```
<ul>
  <li   *ngFor="let item of geoNames | filterBy: userFilter; let index = index;" (click)="showNameG[index] = !showNameG[index]" ><a>{{ item.name }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is good description of *ngFor: 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html